# Comparing table with sql/tsql in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have four tables in SQL Server 2012: `table1, table2, table3`, and a (resultant/output table) `table4`

1. `table1` is truncated and loaded with new data daily.
2. `table1` columns `col1, col2, col3` are similar to `table2` columns `col7, col18, col9`, and to `table3` columns `col9, col11, col7`, so we can load match rows fro `table2` and `table3`

Problem

Looping table1 to check for every row (col1,col2,col3) matches any row in the table2 (col7,col18,col9) then add row in table4 containing information table1.col1,table1.col2,table1.col3, table2.col6,table3.col1,table3.col7 and a column to indicate its an update

- if row (col1,col2,col3) in table1 does not exist in table2 add row in table4 containing information table1.col1,table1.col2,table1.col3, table2.col6,table3.col1,table3.col7 and a column to indicate its an addition
- if row (col7,col18,col9) in table2 does not exist in table1 add row in table4 containing information table1.col1,table1.col2,table1.col3, table2.col6,table3.col1,table3.col7 and a column to indicate its an deletion

return table4 as result

How can we do this with SQL/TSQL only?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you are looking for a `full join` with conditional logic in the `from` clause:

```
insert into table4
select
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    t2.col6,
    t3.col1,
    t3.col7,
    case 
        when t2.col7 is null then 'insert'
        when t1.col1 is null then 'delete'
        else 'update'
    end action
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col7 and t1.col2 = t2.col8  and t1.col3 = t2.col9
full join table3 t3 on t1.col1 = t3.col9 and t1.col2 = t2.col11 and t1.col3 = t3.col7
```

It is not that clear, what you want to do with `table3`. Possibly, you want to `left join` it instead of `full join`, with conditions that check in both preceding tables, like:

```
left join table t3
    on  t3.col9  = coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col7)
    and t3.col11 = coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col8)
    and t3.col7  = coalesce(t1.col3, t2.col9)
```

Comment: table three will only give information (col7,col9,col11) to result if it has any row matching table1.col4 = table3.col16 and table1.col10 = table3.col19

Comment: @huby115: OK I was suspecting this, so you want the `left join` solution at the end of my answer.